# Какие могут быть альтернативы файлам в linux API?

Tags: c++, linux, api

Есть такая задача. У нас запускаются две программы на ОС Linux. Необходимо сделать так чтобы они могли друг с другом сообщаться. Как это возможно реализовать? Через файлы получается не так хорошо как хочется(например после закрытия процесса, остаются старые данные. И при следующем старте программ они могут повлиять негативно на работоспособность программы).

Comment: Сокеты, пайпы ?

Comment: (1) Я проверял пайпы, они работают только внутри одной конкретной программы. Возможно я что-то неправильно понял

(2) Сокеты блокируют работу программы, особенно учитывая что коммуникацию между двумя программами придётся иногда прерывать. Хотя, это конечно же можно было бы вылечить через использование потоков, но не желательно.

Comment: Плохо проверяли. И сокеты, и пайпы работают между разными программами (какой смысл использовать пайпы в пределах одной программы, лол?) и могут быть переведены в неблокирующий режим и/или использоваться в отдельном потоке

Comment: Хорошо. Ладно. А есть ли ещё альтернативы этим двум вариантам?

Comment: А зачем? Подавляющее большинство программ пользуется именно сокетами и пайпами (ну, есть ещё общая память, но её использование нужно заранее согласовать через сокет или пайп)

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо за ответ. Я ещё раз присмотрюсь к этим способам.

Comment: (1) общая база данных. Суть тот-же файл, но есть поддержка персистентности, на случай падения одного из процессов. (2) shared_memory + семафоры (внутри этой памяти). (3) очереди сообщений msgget/msgsnd/msgrcv (4) Разные виды RPC (remote procedure call) ...